# Writing to file clause

Tags: python, class

I have a file in which I have people listed as 'ID Name PhoneNumber Address', like this:

```
1 Mike 0752 Dallas Alley
2 John 0744 Square Avenue
3 Johnny 0923 Corner Street
```

Whenever I try to delete or modify a person it won't let me do so, unless I added the person during program execution. What I mean is, I run my program, and unless I add the person(via an add method I use) right then, I won't be able to modify my file.

I can add people to the file, like I said, but even then, it doesn't check if the ID already exists, even though I have this set up in my method.

I should mention that I have a class based program, with repository-controller-UI structure. The SAVE function that I have in my repository is:

```
def save(self, pers):
        '''
        Saves a person in class Persoana, returns ValueError if the ID already exists
        '''
        for i in self.__persList:
            if(i.idPers == pers.idPers):
                raise ValueError("ID already exists: " +str(i.idPers))
        self.__persList.append(pers)
```

I use this function in my Controller, as follows:

```
def createPerson(self, idPers, nume, telefon, adresa):
        '''
        Creates a person as long as the data introduced is correct
        '''
        i = Persoana(idPers, nume, telefon, adresa)
        self.__valiPers.validare(i)  //checks if the data I put in is alright(name doesn't contain numbers etc.)
        self.__repo.save(i)
```

I use inheritance to make a FileRepository file, which inherits methods/parameters from the initial Repository file.

```
class AgendaFileRepository(AgendaRepository):
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.__file_name = file_name
        AgendaRepository.__init__(self)
        self.__load_from_file()

    def __write_to_file(self):
        l=self.get_persoane()
        f=open(self.__file_name,"w")
        for person in l:
            f.write(repr(person)+'\n')
        f.close()

    def __load_from_file(self):
        try:
            f=open(self.__file_name,"r")
            linie=f.readline().rstrip('\n')
            while linie!="":
                attr=linie.split(" ")
                a=Persoana(attr[0], attr[1], attr[2],attr[3])
                AgendaRepository.save(self, a)
                linie=f.readline().rstrip('\n')
            f.close()
        except IOError:
            raise IOError("File cannot be open")
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("Can't read from file")
        except IndexError:
            raise IndexError("Can't read from file")

    def save(self, pers):
        AgendaRepository.save(self, pers)
        self.__write_to_file()
```

The function that I have in my UI folder is:

```
def addPerson(self):  
        '''
        Adds a person to the file, returns value error if the data isn't valid
        '''
        name=input("Name: ")
        telnumber = input("Tel number: ")
        adress = input("Adress: ")
        idPers=int(input("Id:"))
        try:
            self.__ctrl.createPerson(idPers, name, telnumber, adress)
            print("Added person successfully")            
        except ValueError as ex:
            print(str(ex))
```

Anyway, I realise that this exercise can be done way easier/faster, but the professor wants to make us understand OOP I guess. Anyway, I can write stuff to the file, but it doesn't check if the ID of the person is there already, unless I added the person during program execution. I can't delete/modify people either, unless they have been added during program execution.

Been busting my brains for like 2 hours now with this, checking every line and everything, but I can't seem to crack it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Let the program write a test output (print) when it adds a person. Then you can see if it adds the persons correctly when the program starts.

Comment: Sidenote: You are using/implementing `repr()`/`__repr__()` wrong. That's a string representation for programmers/debugging and the convention is either a string that could be `eval()`ed to get an equal value or somethig in angle brackets that is more or less helpful for a programmer when searching bugs.  You might use `str()`/`__str__()` for this or add dedicated (de)serialization methods. Also the double underscores for ”private” attributes is wrong: Python has no private, that name mangling is for a different purpose. Just use a single underscore to mark implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found the issue. The problem was that the type of i.idPers and pers.idPers wasn't the same. One was a string and the other was an integer, and the equality between them never happened, thus the program never entered the IF loop.